# How to use Flask-Bootstrap in Spyder?

Tags: python, flask, spyder

I'm trying to run the [Flask-Bootstrap sample application](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/tree/master/sample_application) from within Spyder, but I'm not seeing anything when I hit run. It sits for a long time, but I'm pretty sure it's supposed to bring up a webpage, correct? I don't get any error message. It just never does anything as far as I can tell.

When I run via `python run_sample_app.py`, I get an error message `No module named flask_appconfig` despite having installed Flask using `conda install flask`.

I tried installing via `pip install flask-appconfig`, but I have apparently already installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask-appconfig in      /Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask in /Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-appconfig)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-appconfig)
Cleaning up...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `conda` and `pip` are two separate things. Have you tried using `conda` to install `flask-appconfig`?

Comment: Yeah I also tried through conda, which lead me to look the package up via binstar. However the package does not appear to be available under that name for OS X. The same message about already having the package also appears when I try to install via conda.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) When you solve the `flask-appconfig` problem, you need to change the way your `run_sample_app.py` is ran in Spyder. For that you have to press `F6` when the file is focused and select the option `Execute in a new dedicated Python console` or `Execute in an external System terminal`

Comment: I did it, and nothing happens... It claims that Flask is already installed, so I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help, guys! I was just being dumb. I thought surely the application should pull up a browser for me, but I was wrong. It just posts the HTML/CSS to my localhost (127.0.0.1), and I didn't realize that I had to navigate there on my own. Everything is working now. Thanks again!